# Solidity Invalid Address Errors

Tags: solidity, invalid-argument

I am currently doing some research and learning more about how Smart Contracts work (I am using Solidity to write them and compile them, and I am using the geth JS console to interact with them on my PC)

I got my contract deployed onto a simple 2 node network that I made and the functions that I defined in my source code work fine except for the ones that involve addresses.

In the screenshot I provided below I am using the account hash for the second node (what you get when you type eth.coinbase into the console) as a parameter to try and see if the function that I had written works as intended, but I got the errors that you see in the screenshot. I am new to this whole thing so I was wondering if anyone could tell me what it is that I am doing wrong, I don't really know what it is that I should provide for the parameter so that the contract knows what node I am referring to. If someone could point me in the right direction or provide some insight on this, it would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: You sure that’s the right address format? Doesn’t look 160-bit.

Answer (score 0):

In web3js, the address parameters are represented as hex strings. Therefore, you need to send it like:

`ElectionInstance.delegate('0x....');`

See the `web3.isAddress()` [documentation](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3isaddress) for an example.